# (Python Selenium) How do I wait until an element class changes and then do something?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

EX: if an element has the class **123** then I want the program to do something when it changes to **abc**

Right now I'm using a while loop which everybody knows is the least efficient thing to use in the scenario. This is my first time using Selenium

Comment: See the following answer to similar question asked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237129/webdriverwait-for-an-element-attribute-to-change

Comment: Check here. I had a similar question once. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66859094/wait-till-text-in-an-element-is-changed